# Point click callback of Dygraph not working in Polymer Shadow DOM

Tags: polymer, dygraphs

I am creating a Ploymer custom component and using Dygraph to creat a chart. I have added a `pointClickCallback` for the same.

But, when the chart is inside the shadow dom pointClickcallback is not working at all. Although, when I put the chart outside the custom component i.e. in the index.html, the pointClickCallback is working fine.

**EDIT :** `highlightCallback` is working properly inside shadow dom, not the `pointClickCallback`

Can any one tell me what might be the problem.

**UPDATE**

I am not sure whether this is right way of doing it but, please suggest. I am doing like below and it works for me

```
var self = this; // 'this' is not the window object
self.pts = null;
var g = new Dygraph(
    this.$.div_g,
    NoisyData, {
      rollPeriod: 7,
      showRoller: true,

      errorBars: true,
      highlightCallback: function(e, x, pts, row) {
          console.log("highlightCallback --> self.pts", self.pts);
          console.log("highlightCallback", pts);
          self.pts = pts;
          console.log("highlightCallback --> self.pts", self.pts);
      },
      interactionModel : {
          'click' : function(e) {
              console.log("click", e, self.pts);
          }
      },
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pointClickCallback` does not go into the `interactionModel` but is bascially on the same level as the `highlightCallback`. 
So your code should look like this:

```
var g = new Dygraph(
    this.$.div_g,
    NoisyData, {
      rollPeriod: 7,
      showRoller: true,

      errorBars: true,
      highlightCallback: function(e, x, pts, row) {
          console.log("highlightCallback --> self.pts", self.pts);
          console.log("highlightCallback", pts);
          self.pts = pts;
          console.log("highlightCallback --> self.pts", self.pts);
      },
      pointClickCallback: function(e,pt) {
         console.log('Point clicked');
      },
      interactionModel : {
          'click' : function(e) {
              console.log("click", e, self.pts);
          }
      },
    }
  );
```

Comment: yes, exactly `pointClickCallback` is on same level as  `highlightCallback`, but as I mentioned in the question "highlightCallback is working properly inside shadow dom, not the pointClickCallback". Hence, I used `interactionModel`

Comment: I see, there should be no reason why it should not work.
Does this happen in Shadow DOM or ShadyDOM ? 
Using my Polymer wrapper for dygraphs the pointClickCallback does work fine (https://github.com/timeu/dy-graphs)